# Array parsing in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have an array $array1

```
    Array
   (
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [galleryid] => gallery.xml
            [galleryname] => Default
            [createdat] => 9/8/2010 5:55 pm
            [description] => Default
        )
   }
```

when i am running

```
foreach($array1 as $node)
{
 print_r($node) ; 
}
```

am getting

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [galleryid] => gallery.xml
    [galleryname] => Default
    [createdat] => 9/8/2010 5:55 pm
    [description] => Default
)
```

How i can display galleryid and gallery name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like you would access any other [SimpleXMLElement Object:](http://de.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

```
foreach($array1 as $node)
{
    echo $node->galleryname;
    echo $node->galleryid;
}
```

Comment: ... i.e. the array is a one-dimensional array containing objects (which have properties), not a multidimensional array.

Comment: @BlaM judging by [the OPs previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438808/parsing-xml-using-xpath), I'd say the array is a result of an XPath query, so it is singledim.

Answer (score 2):

Both galleryid & galleryname are object properties, you can access object properties with the following syntax.

```
foreach($array1 as $node){
     echo $node->galleryid;
     echo $node->galleryname;
}
```

Plenty of resources online to learn object oriented PHP and the correct syntax for accessing properties and methods.